# How to make ActiveRecord delete associated objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord's `replace` method to... well, replace a collection of associated objects with new ones.

Everything works fine, except for when I delete items, only the association itself is deleted (the `id` is nulled in the database) but the actual associated objects are not.

E.g. I have a `Profile` model, which `has_many` `Skill`s, and when I delete a skill or two, only the profile_id gets removed from the `skills` table, not the entire row.

I want to get rid of the entire row.

Comment: You can destroy all the skills when the profile they're related to is deleted first, so this is done in cascade as deleting the children when a parent is deleted to not leave "orphan" records. You cannot do it the other way around out-of-the-box with Rails (that I'm aware of) since you'll be prone to leave children without parent. You'll have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Please give more detailed behavior that you expect